# Error using xdebug with Ubuntu / Nginx / Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, nginx, visual-studio-code, xdebug, php-7.1

I'm trying to set up PHP debugging on Ubuntu/Nginx with XDebug in Visual Studio Code.

I have the PHP Debug extension installed for Visual Studio Code.

Here's what my `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` looks like

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

When I click on the "listen for XDebug" button in Visual Studio Code, I get this error in Visual Studio Code's console:

```
{ XDebugError: command is not available
at new Response (/home/ben/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:56:19)
at new BreakpointSetResponse (/home/ben/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:207:9)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/ben/.vscode/extensions/felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0/out/xdebugConnection.js:599:20)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

How do I fix this error and set up PHP debugging correctly?